# How to programmatically expand React Reach UI (@reach/menu-button) Menu?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I am using introduction package called `intro.js` and after certain step I would like to click on my dropdown menu and present the dropdown menu. The issue I am having is that `.click` event doesn't work, while `.focus` does. I have `console.log()` which fires but the dropdown never opens for some reason. Here is the code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, {useRef} from 'react'
import { Steps, Hints } from "intro.js-react";
import {
  Menu,
  MenuList,
  MenuButton,
  MenuItem,
  useMenuButtonContext,
} from "@reach/menu-button";



export default function App() {

  const myRef = useRef(null)

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
      stepsEnabled: true,
      initialStep: 0,
      steps: [
        {
          element: ".hello",
          intro: "Hello step"
        },
        {
          element: ".world",
          intro: "World step"
        }
      ],
      hintsEnabled: true,
      hints: [
        {
          element: ".hello",
          hint: "Hello hint",
          hintPosition: "middle-right"
        }
      ]
    })



  // This event fires after 2 seconds of closing the introduction tour
  const onExit = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {myRef.current.click(), console.log("this is the first message")}, 2000);
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Steps
          enabled={state.stepsEnabled}
          steps={state.steps}
          initialStep={state.initialStep}
          onExit={onExit}
        />
             <h1 className="hello">Hello,</h1>
        <hr />
        <h1 className="world">World!</h1>
        <hr />
      <Menu>
      <MenuButton id="example-button" ref={myRef} onClick={()=> console.log('clicked')}>
        Actions <span aria-hidden="true">▾</span>
      </MenuButton>
      <MenuList>
        <MenuItem >
          Download
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem >
          Create a Copy
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem >
          Mark as Draft
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem >
          Delete
        </MenuItem>
      </MenuList>
    </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Basically once I close the introduction tour (modal) I would like to to have dropdown open. Here is a link to Codesandbox of this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-swartz-8b8s6?file=/src/App.js

P.s Sorry for bad code format and no refactoring, this is only a PoC!

Comment: Are you sure `MenuButton` from `@reach/menu-button` supports `ref`? Is it open source so you could check in the source if [forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://reach.tech/menu-button/#menu) (scroll to the end), `MenuButton` uses `mousedown`. I tried dispatching the `mousedown` event and it expanded the menu:

```
const onExit = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      myRef.current.dispatchEvent(new Event("mousedown", { bubbles: true }));
    }, 2000);
};
```

[image: Edit elastic-resonance-bvup6]